# Integrate TFS on-premise with Slack

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, slack-api, slack

**Question**

---

Is there a way to integrate my builds on *TFS On-Premise* (2013) with Slack?

If yes, what are the steps to do so?

**Example**

---

For example when a build fails, I would like to automatically get a message on a Channel in Slack.

**Note**

---

I already have setup a Slack channel and have the WebHook URL for it. Also added Visual Studio Team Services to the Apps in the Slack group integration settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [TfsNotificationRelay](https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay) extension.

> TfsNotificationRelay is an extensible plugin for Team Foundation
>   Server that sends notifications to Slack, HipChat and IRC.
>
> **Supported Events**
>
> - XAML Build completion
> - vNext Build completion*
> - Build quality change
> - Work item update
> - Team project creation/deletion
> - Release creation*
> - Release deployment*
> - Git
> - TFVC  *TFS 2015 only

Comment: Great, we installed the above plugin in our on-premise 2017 tfs server, and it started working like a magic. Thanks. You saved my day.